# A software to monitor GPU temperature changes

Tags: windows, gpu-monitor

It happens quite often that while playing heavy games, my laptop shuts off due to GPU overheat. I need a software that does the following:

- Records GPU temperature
- When the temperature reaches a predefined threshold (say ~80 deg C) it should start off an alarm - in the form of a notification or popup
- Optimizes my programs during gaming to reduce GPU load (optional)

I'm using Windows 8.1 with an AMD GPU.

Answer (score 5):

The only GPU tool I know that does this is [Real Temp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/). I used it shortly and it works really well. It has an extremely small footprint and has a lot of features for monitoring your hardware.

[image]

Pros:

- Portable and free
- High temperature alarm and shutdown feature based on CPU or NVIDIA GPU temperature
- Runs on Windows XP up

Cons:

- Only works on Intel CPUs and NVIDIA GPUs

As an addendum, for a CPU only tool, I would recommend [CoreTemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/).

Comment: Looks good. But I've got an AMD GPU. Any suggestions here?

Comment: @Ranveer I had some bookmarks from sometime back. I will poke around. And actually, I don't have a GPU or a pc to test it right now but it _might_ support AMD gpus, can't recall but I know for a fact it only supports Intel cpus.

Answer (score 5):

I use [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php):

- Records GPU temperature (log)
- When the temperature reaches a predefined threshold (say ~80 deg C) you can configure it so that it starts off an alarm - in the form of a popup message, beep or even email.
- Free but not portable
- In addition to GPU, it also monitors CPU, HD and Fans.

It does not

- Optimize my programs during gaming to reduce GPU load (optional)

Main window:

[image]

Log:

[image]

Event alarm:
[image]

Comment: Ah, I was looking for this. Knew it but couldn't remember the name. This is the answer imo.

Answer (score 4):

I use GPU-Z. I got it [from here](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/).

[image]

Their authors explain advantages of their software as

> - Supports NVIDIA, ATI and Intel graphics devices
> - Displays adapter, GPU and display information
> - Displays overclock, default clocks and 3D clocks (if available)
> - Includes a GPU load test to verify PCI-Express lane configuration
> - Validation of results
> - GPU-Z can create a backup of your graphics card BIOS
> - No installation required, optional installer is available
> - Support for Windows XP / Vista / Windows 7 / Windows 8 (both 32 and 64 bit versions are supported)
> - .. and yes, the author of CPU-Z has granted us permission to use a name similar to his product.

[image]

This is free to get and use.

- You can choose "Republic of Gamers" skin, if you like.

Comment: I like it but it has no alarm.